# PHP Weird IF statement result on boolean?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

So i have this code:

```
echo $argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate];
if ($argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate]==TRUE){
    echo " It's true ";
}
```

And the result is:

true It's true

or

false It's true

Do you know why?
I tried to change IF to var=TRUE, var===TRUE, var=="true", var=1

None of these worked. I haven't got that kind of problem earlier, it's really weird...

P.S. If statement is inside two foreach loops. I don't know if that matters somehow...

**EDIT**

I changed echo to var_dump, and the result is:

```
string(5) "false" It's true
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the part of the script:

```
$iterate2=0;
foreach ($UpdateData as $key => $value) {
    $sql.="UPDATE `addtmptable` SET ";
    $sql.="$key = CASE ";
    $iterate=0;

        foreach ($value as $val) {

            $sql.="WHEN user = '$UpdateDataU[$iterate]' THEN $val ";

                var_dump($argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate]);
                if ($argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate]==true){
                    echo " It's true ";
                }
            $iterate++;
        }

    $sql.=";";
    $iterate2++;
}
```

I stopped on this, i want to fire the inner foreach if the statement is true

Comment: You should show what the variable actually contains. Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump), not `echo`.

Comment: Very unclear question. I have no idea what you want to do

Comment: I suspect that $argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate]; is a string containing 'true' or 'false'.
as mentioned by @mario, use var_dump instead

Comment: This should not have any impact on the code but try change the "TRUE" to "true" in other words, not in caps. Also has @mario said post the var_dump on what you want

Comment: do you tried to use true (lowercase) instead of TRUE (uppercase) ?

Comment: While its in the loop are you changing the value?

Comment: lowercase true doesn't change anything

Comment: @CameronSpanos No, i'm not. I'm only changing $iterate2 and $iterate

Comment: Could you post the whole loop because there is nothing wrong with your conditional statement logic

Comment: Show the whole code; the way it's defined in your question doesn't show any unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing a string against a boolean value.

The only strings that evaluate to false are "" and "0".

```
if (strtolower($argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate]) != "false") {
    echo " It's true ";
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been thinking what's wrong for an hour! :)

Comment: This answer assumes, of course, that your value will always be the string "false" when you expect it to evaluate to false...  The side effect here is that "fals" (typo of false) will evaluate to true.

Comment: Yes, i understand. My problem was that i used js to pass variable that was true if checkbox was checked, but i didn't think js would put tru or false into a tring ;) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A string [with any value](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) will always evaluate to boolean value `true`. Change your comparison to `$argi[2][$iterate2][$iterate] == "TRUE"` instead.